# php - How to set a href url in blade

Tags: php, laravel, href

I'm currently working with **Laravel** (because my school told me to) and php and I really don't get it.
I'm working with **blade.php** which recieves **values from a ViewControlle**(not quite if it works like this but I think so). The **value contains name** and and a **url** for wikipedia which leads to the right article for the name in a table.

**So what I'm trying to accomplish is**

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin">Berlin</a>
```

**So my code is currently:**

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
<td>
<tr><a href="{{$city["Url"]}}">{{$city["Name"]}}</a></tr>
</td>
@endforeach
```

**and it does not work while**

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
<td>
<tr>{{$city["Name"]}}</tr>
</td>
@endforeach
```

works perfectly fine...

I've already searched for an answer but all answers are written for php with

```
echo '...';
```

I really don't get it.

**Thanks in advance ^^**

Comment: $city["Url"] show me output of this.

Comment: Can you show us the code in your controller so we can see how you’re making `$cities`?

Comment: Are you sure your `$city` array contains a node named `Url`? And with the uppercase `U`?

Comment: what does the `<tr>{{$city["Name"]}}</tr>` gives?

Comment: change ```{{$city["Url"]}``` to ```{{$city['Url']}``` single quotes html will see the " and think thats the end off the value

Comment: Thanks for your help I have been really busy these day and I checked the answers and marked the solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<tr><a href="{{$city["Url"]}}">{{$city["Name"]}}</a></tr>
```

to

```
 <tr><a href="{{$city['Url']}}">{{$city["Name"]}}</a></tr>
```

**or you can do it like this:**

```
<tr><a href='{{$city["Url"]}}'>{{$city["Name"]}}</a></tr>
```

Comment: Sorry that it took me so long to respond. This worked perfect! Thank you^^

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
    <td>
        <tr>
            <a href="{{ $city->Url }}">{{ $city->Name }}</a>
        </tr>
    </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This did not work maybe because city is not an object which contains an url, so im am not able to access via ->